# WSO2 IS 5.1.0 Empty SignatureValue and DigestValue in SAML Assertion

Tags: spring, wso2, saml, spring-saml, wso2-identity-server

When I get SAML Assertion from Identity Server, DigestValue and SignatureValue are empty :\

Assertion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="lhgklipdcdifghfbehlmdbbghndlgdpbdeggppjd" IssueInstant="2016-12-28T10:22:35.668Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">localhost</saml2:Issuer><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><ds:Reference URI="#lhgklipdcdifghfbehlmdbbghndlgdpbdeggppjd"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="xs"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue/></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue/><ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature><saml2:Subject><saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">admin@carbon.super</saml2:NameID><saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><saml2:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="a4feh03406aeih7f2g73aaai048a3f1" NotOnOrAfter="2016-12-28T10:27:35.663Z" Recipient="http://localhost:22222/console/saml/SSO"/></saml2:SubjectConfirmation><saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><saml2:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="a4feh03406aeih7f2g73aaai048a3f1" NotOnOrAfter="2016-12-28T10:27:35.663Z" Recipient="https://192.168.100.120:9443/oauth2/token"/></saml2:SubjectConfirmation></saml2:Subject><saml2:Conditions NotBefore="2016-12-28T10:22:35.668Z" NotOnOrAfter="2016-12-28T10:27:35.663Z"><saml2:AudienceRestriction><saml2:Audience>onGeoConsoleTest2</saml2:Audience><saml2:Audience>https://192.168.100.120:9443/oauth2/token</saml2:Audience></saml2:AudienceRestriction></saml2:Conditions><saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2016-12-28T10:22:35.676Z" SessionIndex="5d427a5b-9392-47f8-84a8-8faf5a2fc029"><saml2:AuthnContext><saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef></saml2:AuthnContext></saml2:AuthnStatement><saml2:AttributeStatement><saml2:Attribute Name="role" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"><saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Internal/subscriber</saml2:AttributeValue><saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Application/ongeo-auth</saml2:AttributeValue><saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Application/api-store</saml2:AttributeValue><saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Internal/everyone</saml2:AttributeValue><saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">admin</saml2:AttributeValue><saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Application/api-publisher</saml2:AttributeValue><saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Application/ongeo-console</saml2:AttributeValue><saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Internal/cg_unpublisher</saml2:AttributeValue><saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Application/admin_Testujemy_PRODUCTION</saml2:AttributeValue><saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Internal/cg_publisher</saml2:AttributeValue></saml2:Attribute></saml2:AttributeStatement></saml2:Assertion>
```

Service Provider configuration:

[image: Service Provider configuration]

Please, help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was on Spring SAML extension side. Signature have been deleted from assertion in `WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl` in method  `processAuthenticationResponse`, but when I set property `releaseDOM` to `false` it is working fine.